# How to add easing to this JQuery script?

Tags: jquery, hover, easing

I want to add easing to this JQuery hover menu script, how can I do that?

```
$("#navi_bakery").hover(function(){
        $("#navi_bakery img").animate({
            paddingTop:"0px"
            },100);
    },function(){
        $("#navi_bakery img").animate({
            paddingTop:"17px"
            },100);
        });
```

Comment: Here's a cheat sheet I found. Do your research. http://easings.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy, you just need to choose your easing  method. Generic example:

```
    $(element).animate({
        properties: {top: '17px'}
        duration: 1000, 
        easing: 'method', 
        complete: callback});
```

Easing methods and examples here: http://easings.net/

Comment: How can I shorthand it to add "EaseInOutExpo" to this script?

Comment: `EaseInOutExpo` won't work unless you are also running a plugin that adds easings - such as jQueryUI, linked below, or the plugin mentioned on that linked page. As said in my answer below, the only easings included in regular jQuery without extra plugins are `swing` and `linear` (your site might already use jQueryUI, it's quite common). When you've added the plugin, add the name of the easing as a string as an argument after the duration, like in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$("#navi_bakery img").animate({top: 0}, 400, 'swing');
```

The string at the end is the easing type. By default there's `swing` and `linear`, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and various  other plugins add more.